# Динамическое добавление слайдера на нужной ширине экрана

Tags: javascript

Как добавить slick slider для нужного разрешения экрана?
Инициализация слайдера:

```
$('.slider').slick({
accessibility: true,
autoplay: true,
});
```

Я на заданном разрешении добавляю нужный класс для инициализации слайдера:

```
 function replaceClass(){
 var block = document.querySelector(".block");
    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 500px)').matches) {
     block.classList.add('slider');
 } else {
  block.classList.remove('slider');
 }
 };

replaceClass();
$(window).resize(replaceClass);
```

Но потом, если увеличить ширину >500 px, класс 'slider' с блока убирается, но слайдер все равно остается висеть на блоке((
Спасибо!!

Comment: Убрать класс и содержимое блока - разные вещи.

Comment: Содержимое блока подключается к блоку с заданным классом. Если слайдер не находит для себя блок с заданным классом он должен исчезнуть или undefined показать? Я так думала) По аналогии с css = добавляем класс, меняем состояние/внешний вид

Comment: Когда подключается - да, ищет блок с классом и вставляет туда html. Но если класс удалить, html никуда не денется )

Comment: Т.е. подход для добавления слайдера на нужном расширении путем добавления класса неверный получается(

Comment: Он правильный. Только при смене разрешения нужно или уничтожать весь html в блоке слайдера, либо вызывать destroy, если у него есть такая функция

Comment: Да, точно!! У него есть метод $('.your-slider').slick('unslick'); Спасибо!!)